# How to programmatically navigate in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have a screen named ChooseUser. And a file named ChooseUserScreen.js which I want to navigate to once signIn is done. But its not working. Its showing this error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: navigate
```

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, Block, Input, Button } from 'galio-framework';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

class SignIn extends Component {
    state = {  
        tochooseuser: false  
    }
    signIn() {
        this.setState({tochooseuser: true })
    }  
    render() {
        if (this.state.tochooseuser === true) {
            navigate('ChooseUser')
        }
        return (
           <Button round color="info" style={ styles.btn } onPress={ this.signIn.bind(this) }>Sign in</Button>
        );
    }
}

export default SignIn;
```

Comment: Are you using some kind of navigation component?

Comment: You should take a look at React Navigation.

Comment: Do I have to install any kind of library here? If so which one?

Comment: @Auticcat No, afaik

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it with

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ChooseUser')
```

inside signIn()